# About minimal angle between nonzero subspaces $\mathcal{R},\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

For nonzero subspaces $\mathcal{R},\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, the minimal angle between $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ is defined to be the number $0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$ that satisfies 
$$\cos(\theta_{\min})=\displaystyle \max_{\substack{u\in\mathcal{R}\\ \|u\|_2=1}}\,\,\max_{\substack{v\in\mathcal{N}\\ \|v\|_2=1}}v^Tu.$$
Now, I have two questions:

1. Why $\theta_{\min}=0$ if and only if $\mathcal{R}\cap\mathcal{N}\neq0$?
2. Why $\theta_{\min}=\pi/2$ if and only if $\mathcal{R}\bot\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: Great questions! What are your thoughts? Have you worked out examples in 3-space just to try to understand?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did not looked into the issue from this perspective. How ever, I think when dim(R)=dim(N)=1, then this is easy.

Comment: In the following, I wrote an answer to the second question, whether this is the right answer?

Comment: That whole "try a simple example" thing is a very powerful technique for developing proofs; I recommend it highly.

Comment: @ John Hughes, I have tried to understand these issues. But, I really don't realize the concept of "minimal" here. In fact, we use the statement "minimal angle" in order to describe the angle between two subspaces, while we define it by maximum of something. Is that possible that you explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

If $u\neq0$ and $v\neq0$, then
$$|v^Tu|=|\langle u,v\rangle|=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2\left|\langle \frac{u}{\|u\|_2},\frac{v}{\|v\|_2}\rangle\right|\leq \|u\|_2\|v\|_2\sup_{\substack{u\in\mathcal{R}\\ \|u\|_2=1}}\,\,\sup_{\substack{v\in\mathcal{N}\\ \|v\|_2=1}}|v^Tu|\\=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2\cos(\theta_{\min}).$$
Now, it is obvious that if $\mathcal{R}\bot\mathcal{N}$, then $v^Tu=0$ for every $u\in\mathcal{R}, v\in\mathcal{N}$. So based on above definition we have $\displaystyle \max_{\substack{u\in\mathcal{R}\\ \|u\|_2=1}}\,\,\max_{\substack{v\in\mathcal{N}\\ \|v\|_2=1}}v^Tu=0$ and hence $\cos(\theta)=0$. Therefore, $\theta_{\min}=\pi/2$.

Comment: That looks right to me. Except that in the inequality phase, $u$ and $v$ shifted from being unbound to being bound (in the "sup") part. In fact, the whole first paragraph seems like it has no purpose. Better perhaps to start with the second paragraph ("Now, it is obvious...") And change the first occurrence of $\theta$ to $\theta_\text{min}$.